# Google Places API - How much can I uplift the quota with uplift quota request form?

Tags: iphone, ios, google-places-api

I am the manager of an iOS application and it uses Google Places API. Right now I am limited to 100,000 requests and during our testing, one or two users could use up to 2000 requests per day (without autocomplete). This means that only about 50 to 200 people will be able to use the app per day before I run out of quota. I know I will need to fill out the uplift request form when the app launches to get more quota but I still feel that I will need a very large quota based on these test results. Can anyone help me with this issue?

Note: I do not want to launch the app until I know I will be able to get a larger quota.

Answer (score 0):

First up, put your review request in sooner rather than later so I have time to review it and make sure it complies with our Terms of Service.

Secondly, how are your users burning 2k requests per day? Would caching results help you lower your request count?

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same problem!

Is it possible to use [Places library of the Google Maps Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places?hl=zh) which gives the quota on each end user instead of an API key so that the quota will grow as user grows. [See here](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/uplift?hl=zh_TW)

Theoretically I think it's possible to do that since it just need a webView or javascript runtime to use the library, but didn't see anyone seems to use this approach.